# Error when migrating from angular 15 to angular 16 when adding provideClientHydration

Tags: angular, angular-universal, transloco

After migrating from angular 15 to angular 16, using universal, if I add provideClientHydration to my AppModule I get the error

```
ERROR Error: When using the default fallback, a fallback language must be provided in the config!
    at getNextLangs (./node_modules/@ngneat/transloco/fesm2020/ngneat-transloco.mjs:318:19)
    at handleFailure (./node_modules/@ngneat/transloco/fesm2020/ngneat-transloco.mjs:898:67)
    at error (./node_modules/@ngneat/transloco/fesm2020/ngneat-transloco.mjs:568:25)
    at onError (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/catchError.js:13:51)
    at _error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:43:21)
    at error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at onError (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/tap.js:31:28)
    at _error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:43:21)
    at error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at <anonymous> (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/retry.js:60:36)
```

The same if I add it to the AppServerModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [provideClientHydration()]
})
export class AppServerModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a library that is causing the error.
Client hydration is currently not suporting i18n

https://angular.io/guide/hydration#i18n

Or if it is only a component, you can use

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: {ngSkipHydration: 'true'},
})
class ExampleCmp {}
```

Check out the entire docs

https://angular.io/guide/hydration

Good luck